# Checking info in API in an Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In an Alexa Skill, I have an intent of ordering an ice cream. I know I can check some information in an API or whatever function I have built inside my Python code, but only if that function is literally atomical.

If I have slots, asking for more information, I cannot check for api info or other personal functions, because having slots in Alexa is not like having slots in a chatbot, for example. **There is no "dialog tree"** or anything similar.

The Ice cream example is simple, but I tried first on doing this before moving on something more complex.

This would be the very basic format of the intent:

[image]

But what I want is during this execution, get some information, inside the intent!

[image]

I have searched everywhere, and I have not found anything useful. I asked the Alexa Developer support, and they told me to check `Dialog`. This was also part of the answer:

> Skill interaction model completely depends on slots defined in your skill. But you can even make it more dynamic depending on no of slot values provided by user but it will always from interaction model already defined in your skill.
>
> You can't create dynamic response based on the data you are getting from APIs or from skill.

But seeing other Alexa skills that are deployed, I guess it should be possible!

What I thought on doing is several functions like:

- get the icecream: only that, getting an icecream flavour. Identifying the flavour in python and calling the api. Saving the flavour in a slot/dynamodb.
- Add something: Everytime the user wants to add something (like whipped cream), call this function. Checking the api depending on what the user wants to add.

This makes it a bit dirty in my opinion, and makes the user lose a bit of flow with Alexa, but might do the job. But is there any way to do it directly in only one function (even though it is atomical)?